# Error inflating SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to implement a swiperefreshlayout using the following code in my fragment,

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/recentList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="@color/grey" >
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Whens tarring the activity i get the error "Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRfreshLayout"

I have never used this control before though i am currently using other controls from v4 support library without issue.